# How to install justext package using Conda install when virtual environment is created?

Tags: anaconda, conda, python-3.4

I created virtual environment for python 3.4 version.I cant able to use pip from my network. I cant able to download files even. So i created virtual environment and started to install packages using **conda** install.

When i was using this command `conda install -c syllabs_admin justext`, i'm getting notification from my server like:

> The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:
>     python                          pkgs/free::python-3.4.5-0 --> pkgs/main::python-2.7.17-h9bab390_0

Can someone actually help me how to install this justext package for my python version 3.4 using conda install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. There is no way that you can use `conda install` with any public channel to install `justext` and your python version. Checking the search function on [anaconda.org](https://anaconda.org/search?q=justext), there are only two channels that provide `justext`:

```
moustik / justext 2.2.0 
syllabs_admin / justext 2.2.0
```

Unfortunately, both have only python 2.7 packaged versions of the module.

you should try to fix your networking issues instead. It sounds really werid that `conda install` would be working while you claim to not be able to even download any files. Please talk to your IT department or Sys Admin about it or ask another question posting the errors you are getting when using `pip install` or `wget https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6c/5f/c7b909b4b864ebcacfac23ce2f6f01a50c53628787cc14b3c06f79464cab/jusText-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`